# Static assertion failed error when trying to use std::vector<std::thread>

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have the below class and it's header file. When I include the line `std::vector<std::thread> threads;` in `ProducerManager.h`, I get the error shown at the bottom of this question. I have gone through multiple SO questions where the issue was not using std::move() to move the thread into the vector, however, apparently since I am doing it by rvalue it should work. But I get this weird error I don't understand. Could anyone be so kind as to help me out?

```
// ProducerManager.h

#include <thread>
#include <queue>

#include "Producer.h"

class ProducerManager {
  public:
    ProducerManager(std::queue<std::string> *buffer, Semaphore *items);
    int run();
  private:
    std::queue<std::string> *buffer;
    Semaphore *items;
    bool empty_page_reached = false;
    unsigned int max_threads = 50;
    unsigned int num_pages = 0;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;   // If I remove this line, I no longer get the error
    std::vector<Producer*> producers;
    std::queue<int> pids;
};
```

```
// ProducerManager.cc

#include "ProducerManager.h"

ProducerManager::ProducerManager(std::queue<std::string> *buffer, Semaphore *items) {
  this->buffer = buffer;
  this->items = items;
}

int ProducerManager::run(void) {
  ...
}
```

```
// main.cc

#include <string>
#include <thread>

#include "ProducerManager.h"
#include "Consumer.h"
#include "Semaphore.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::queue<std::string> *buffer = new std::queue<std::string>();
  Semaphore *items = new Semaphore(0);

  // Testing with just one consumer
  Consumer *c1 = new Consumer(buffer, items);
  std::thread cth1(&Consumer::perform, c1);

  ProducerManager pm(buffer, items);
  std::thread pm_thread(&ProducerManager::run, pm);

  pm_thread.join();
  cth1.join();

  delete c1;

  return 0;
}
```

#### Error:

```
/usr/include/c++/9.2.1/bits/stl_uninitialized.h: In instantiation of ‘_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::thread*, std::vector<std::thread> >; _ForwardIterator = std::thread*]’:
/usr/include/c++/9.2.1/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:307:37:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::thread*, std::vector<std::thread> >; _ForwardIterator = std::thread*; _Tp = std::thread]’
/usr/include/c++/9.2.1/bits/stl_vector.h:555:31:   required from ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with _Tp = std::thread; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::thread>]’ProducerManager.h:6:7:   required from ‘constexpr std::_Head_base<_Idx, _Head, false>::_Head_base(_UHead&&) [with _UHead = ProducerManager&; long unsigned int _Idx = 1; _Head = ProducerManager]’/usr/include/c++/9.2.1/tuple:349:38:   required from ‘static std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<typename std::decay<_Tp>::type, typename std::decay<_Args>::type ...> > std::thread::__make_invoker(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = int (ProducerManager::*)(); _Args = {ProducerManager&}; typename std::decay<_Tp>::type = int (ProducerManager::*)()]’/usr/include/c++/9.2.1/thread:131:22:   required from ‘std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = int (ProducerManager::*)(); _Args = {ProducerManager&}; <template-parameter-1-3> = void]’main.cc:17:50:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9.2.1/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:127:72: error: static assertion failed: result type must be constructible from value type of input range  127 |       static_assert(is_constructible<_ValueType2, decltype(*__first)>::value,
```

Comment: one of the errors points to `ProducerManager.h` line 6 which is `#include<Producer>`, another error is in `main`. Please include a [mcve]

Comment: @idclev463035818 Sorry about that. I have included all the Producer and related files. I have removed unnecessary sections and replaced them with ...'s. I tested that the compilation was the same without them.

Comment: The error message  seems because the copy constructor of the vector of threads is triggered in main.cc

Comment: @nsm It seems to be coming from the line `ProducerManager pm(buffer, items)`. I am guessing it's because that is when the vector of threads is initialized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make it

```
std::thread pm_thread(&ProducerManager::run, std::ref(pm));
// or
std::thread pm_thread(&ProducerManager::run, &pm);
```

`std::thread`'s constructor takes arguments by value. As originally written, it attempts to copy `pm`, but `ProducerManager` is not copyable (because its member `std::vector<std::thread> threads` is not copyable, because `std::thread` is not copyable).